How to properly concatenate multiple XPaths and how to add spaces between them?
I'm trying to create my own personalized RSS Feed for an Italian institutional site. The site in question is this, belonging to an Italian municipality. The idea would be to use the PolitePol online tool, generate the RSS Feed (since the one incorporated into the site doesn't satisfy me, not always creating new elements if there are already too many) and send everything on a Telegram channel via the RSS-to-Telegram-Bot. I correctly identified the essential elements for my post, namely Title (with td[1]), Description (with td[4]) and finally the Link (with td[5]). However, still in the Title section, I would like to concatenate other information, namely that contained in td[2] and that contained in td[5]. The code I've used so far has been this:
concat('Atto numero ', td[1]/child::node(), '                                                                          Tipo: ', td[2]/child::node(), '  ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀                      Data: ',td[5]/child::node())

The solution I adopted is certainly very rudimentary, but for now I haven't found anything else to get to the bottom of; the result is obviously terrible. At this point I ask you, is it possible to make a code like this to allow me to put the various XPaths in the title but put them in separate lines?
What I would like to achieve:
Atto numero 0203/2024
Tipo: Manifesti
Data: 20/06/2024

REVISIONE SEMESTRALE DELLE LISTE ELETTORALI

What I get instead:
Atto numero 0203/2024 ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ Tipo: Manifesti ⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ Data: 20/06/2024

REVISIONE SEMESTRALE DELLE LISTE ELETTORALI

I tried the code above, however the result was not the best, having poorly defined spaces and messy text.

Try using a more specific xpath concat("Atto numero ", //div[@id="secondary"]//tr[1]/td[1]/text(), " Tipo: ", //div[@id="secondary"]//tr[1]/td[2]/text(), " Data: ", //div[@id="secondary"]//tr[1]/td[5]/text()). Result: Atto numero 0203/2024 Tipo: Manifesti Data: 20/06/2024

I took note of your code, I will wait for the trigger to activate to see if the format of the new news is as desired.  However, I must note that by doing so it only takes one element, whereas in my case it took them all.  Can I still put child::node() or would I distort it?

You can try child::node() of course

@LMC Hi, did I end up getting the same result as before? do you have any other solutions? I also tried entering '
' but it did not work.

You can try this concat("Atto numero ", //div[@id="secondary"]//tr[1]/td[1]/text(), "\nTipo: ", //div[@id="secondary"]//tr[1]/td[2]/text(), "\nData: ", //div[@id="secondary"]//tr[1]/td[5]/text()) which works on browser's dev console but you are tied to whatever that tool does.

Try this:
(concat("Atto numero ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[1][string-length(normalize-space())=9]), concat("Tipo: ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[2]), concat("Data: ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[5]), concat("", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[4]))

OR xpath 2:
for $x in //table[@class="tablesorter"]
return
    (
        concat("Atto numero ", $x//tr[7]/td[1][string-length(normalize-space())=9]),
        concat("Tipo: ", $x//tr[7]/td[2]),
        concat("Data: ", $x//tr[7]/td[5]),
        concat("", $x//tr[7]/td[4])
    )

Result:
Atto numero 0203/2024
Tipo: Manifesti
Data: 20/06/2024
REVISIONE SEMESTRALE DELLE LISTE ELETTORALI

PS: Change the numbers in the tr, td tags for accurate searches.

Hi, first of all thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, with the site I'm using (PolitePol) it gives me an error, saying this: XPath error: Invalid expression in (concat("Atto numero ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[1][string-length(normalize-space())=9]), concat("Tipo: ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[2]), concat("Data: ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[5]), concat("", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[4])).

I tried to modify it but then it distorts the result; in fact, modifying it like this works: concat("Atto numero ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[1][string-length(normalize-space())=9], concat("Tipo: ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[2]), concat("Data: ", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[5]), concat("", //table[@class="tablesorter"]//tr[7]/td[4])) but with a horrendous result. Do you have any other suggestions?

Hi! Perhaps the problem lies in the syntax or peculiarities of the XPath implementation on the PolitePol platform.

I have never used PolitePol, but I think my solution is optimal on xpath 1, 2. Maybe you should experiment with regular expressions. If possible xpath 2 with string-join() and tokenize().

I'm not familiar with PolitePol, but if that doesn't work for you, then why not use an HTML/XML parser, like the command-line tool xidel, to create your own RSS feed?
With "direct element constructors":
$ xidel -s "http://alboserrata.asmenet.it/index.php?sez=p" -e '(
  <rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
      <title>{//title/text()}</title>
      <link>{$url}</link>
      {for $x in //table[@class="tablesorter"]/tbody/tr[td[@style=""]] return
      <item>
        <title>{$x/concat(td[1],", ",td[2])}</title>
        <description>{$x/concat(td[3],", ",td[4])}</description>
        <pubDate>{$x/td[5]/text()}</pubDate>
        <link>{resolve-uri($x/td[7]/a/@href)}</link>
      </item>}
    </channel>
  </rss>
)' --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent

Or with "computed constructors":
$ xidel -s "http://alboserrata.asmenet.it/index.php?sez=p" -e '
  element rss {attribute version {"2.0"},
    element channel {
      element title {//title/text()},
      element link {$url},
      for $x in //table[@class="tablesorter"]/tbody/tr[td[@style=""]] return
      element item {
        element title {$x/concat(td[1],", ",td[2])},
        element description {$x/concat(td[3],", ",td[4])},
        element pubDate {$x/td[5]/text()},
        element link {resolve-uri($x/td[7]/a/@href)}
      }
    }
  }
' --output-node-format=xml --output-node-indent

You can totally customize it the way you like. The output for these queries:
<rss version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title>Albo pretorio on-line Comune di Serrata</title>
    <link>http://alboserrata.asmenet.it/index.php?sez=p</link>
    <item>
      <title>0209/2024, Avvisi vari</title>
      <description>MINISTERO PUBBLICA ISTRUZIONE, (Esami di Stato per l&#x2019;abilitazione all&#x2019;esercizio della libera professione di Perito agrario e di Perito agrario laureato per la sessione 2024)</description>
      <pubDate>28/06/2024</pubDate>
      <link>http://alboserrata.asmenet.it/allegati.php?id_doc=28100615&amp;sez=p&amp;data1=28/06/2024&amp;data2=25/07/2024</link>
    </item>
    <item>
      <title>0208/2024, Delibere di giunta  </title>
      <description>Comune di SERRATA, APPROVAZIONE ORGANIGRAMMA E FUNZIONIGRAMMA DELL&apos;ENTE</description>
      <pubDate>27/06/2024</pubDate>
      <link>http://alboserrata.asmenet.it/allegati.php?id_doc=27120629&amp;sez=p&amp;data1=27/06/2024&amp;data2=12/07/2024</link>
    </item>
    [...]
  </channel>
</rss>


Similar answer.

Please tell me if you're using Windows. If you are, then I'll edit my answer, because these commands, including the use of quotes, are for Linux.
